# No suitable graphics card is found error in Visual Studio 2010 debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

When i try to run my program i get this error:

> "No suitable graphics card is found. Could not find a Direct3D device
>   that supports the XNA Framework Hi-Def profile. Verify that a suitable
>   graphics device is installed. Make sure your desktop isn't locked, and
>   that no other application is running in full screen mode. Avoid
>   running under Remote Desktop or as a Windows service. Check the
>   display properties to make sure hardware acceleration is set to Full."

I tryied to search: i can't set Rearch profile because i have to use Hi-Def libraries. I tryied to uninstall and install XNA 4.0 and .NET 4.5 but it doesn't work.
What i should do?

My laptop:

- Pentium (R) Dual-Core CPU 2.2GHz
- RAM: 4GB
- Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit
- DirectX 11
- Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family
- Intel Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) 4500MHD

Answer (score 1):

Your graphics card does not meet the XNA requirements. Why do you have to use Hi-Def? Your DirectX sounds up to date, but those are still very low end cards. Read the exact specifications on [Shawn Hargreaves](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx) blog for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your XNA project settings in the corresponding tab to target Reach profile, not the HD one. This will probably let you run the app, but beware the performance may be very low.

You may still be able to reference the HD libs and call their methods. Try to solve specific problems you have with that approach instead.

But really get a discrete graphics card if you want high performance and less problems.